# Getting Issue with BigQuery

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running a sample Java code where I am trying to get the description of BigQuery table. When I run it in my local, its working fine. But when I go to google cloud and deploy the jar in GCS and run it via dataproc, I'm getting below issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;  
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:88)  
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)  
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)  
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)  
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)  
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:665)
```

Sample Code:

```
private static BigQuery bigquery = null;
    static {
        bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId("**PROJECT_ID**")
                .build().getService();
    }
 public static void getTable(String projectId, String datasetName, String tableName) {
        try {
           TableId tableId = TableId.of(projectId, datasetName, tableName);
            Table table = bigquery.getTable(tableId);
            System.out.println("Table info: " + table.getDescription());
        } catch (BigQueryException e) {
            System.out.println("Table not retrieved. \n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

pom.xml - This is the only dependency I have in my pom.xml. I have seen suggestions from earlier pos to check the guava dependency conflict, but in my case i don't see a conflict as I don't have the other dependency which can conflict with this.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.116.10</version>
</dependency>
```

In the Dataproc ui, I am submitting this job by passing jobtype as Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. There was a conflict in guava library

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-shared-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>0.13.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
       <version>1.116.10</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
               <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
               <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
               <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
               <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

And relocated the com.google.com package to shaded

```
<relocations>
  <relocation>
    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>                               
    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
  </relocation>
</relocations>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` usually indicates that two different versions of an API are in use, and the compiled code expects a different version than the one actually present at the deployment site. In this case, it seems that `com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors` is the conflicting dependency. IIRC it is part of Google Guava.

Check the version history of guava if the method `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` has been modified lately, and compare the deployed guava version to your local one.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier that I just have one dependency in my pom, and I have tried excluding guava from big query dependency and add it separately, that also didn't work for me.